# How to install Parity UI on Ubuntu?

Tags: parity, parity-wallet

I have installed Parity on Ubuntu successfully, but unable to install its UI. The following command:

```
sudo snap install parity-ui
```

is not working and ending up with an error:

```
user@ant-a7-surinder:~$ sudo snap install parity-ui
[sudo] password for user: 
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Fetch and check assertions for snap "parity-ui" (10) (Get https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/assertions/snap-revision/suvnLkTtQB2e2zZlvi9tBKGBLoISrVIOmJNelKAcVdTuwaPXV0VzizWZZnU6ED45?max-format=0: dial tcp xx.xx.xx.xx:443: getsockopt: connection refused)
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After lot of research I found solution of my question. "snapd" is essential before installing parity-ui. Below two commands solved my problem.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
```